# R create a vector with loop structure

Tags: r

I have a list, `listDFs`, where each element is a data frame. Each data frame has a different number of rows and the same number of columns.

I should create a vector beginning from *listDFs[[i]]$Name* extracting all the *i* element from the list.

I thought to use a loop such:

```
vComposti <- c()
for(j in 1:10){vComposti <- c(listDFs[[j]]$Name)}
```

But the result is a vector containing only the first level (*listDFs[[1]]$Name*) of the list.

Where I wrong?? Do you have any suggestion??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you have is in this line:

```
vComposti <- c(listDFs[[j]]$Name)
```

Each time through your loop, you are *re-assigning* a new value to `vComposti` and *overwriting* the previous value.

In general it is preferable to pre-allocate the vector and fill it element by element:

```
vComposti <- rep(NA, 10)
for(j in 1:10){
    vComposti[j] <- c(listDFs[[j]]$Name)
}
```

But it's also not clear to me exactly what you're expecting the result to be. You create a vector, but it looks like you are trying to store an entire data frame column in each element of the vector. If that's the case you may actually be looking for a result that's a list:

```
vComposti <- vector("list",10)
for(j in 1:10){
    vComposti[[j]] <- c(listDFs[[j]]$Name)
}
```

Another, somewhat more sophisticated, option may be to use `lapply`:

```
lapply(listDFs,FUN = "[","Name")
```

Comment: Yes, `lapply` is the best choice but, the return of `lapply` is a list . How should I do to transform it in a data frame?

Comment: @Riccardo, since a `data.frame` **is** a list, you can simply use `as.data.frame` on the result of `lapply`

Comment: I tried it but the R console give this error: _Error in data.frame(list(Name = c("A",: arguments imply differing number of rows: 61, 57, 58, 56, 55, 53, 54, 51, 52, 48_ .

Comment: I solved the last problem with this: `df <-data.frame(matrix(unlist(lComposti),byrow=T))`