# Explaining a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I'm very new to R, and much more new to programming in R. I have the following question and its answer (which is not mine). I've trying to understand why some values, from where they are obtained, why they are used, etc.

> Question: Make the vector 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 with a for loop. Start
>   with x=numeric() and fill this vector with the for loop

I know I have to create x=numeric() so I can fill it with the result obtained from the loop.

The answer from a classmate was:

```
> x <- numeric()
> for(i in 1:8){   
      if(i==1){                ## Why ==1 and not 0, or any other value   
          x[i] <- 3              
      }else{   
          x[i] <- x[i-1]+2  ### And why i-1   
     }
```

I'm having similar problems in questions like:

> Make a for loop that adds the second element of a vector to the first,
>   subtracts the third element from the result, adds the fourth again and
>   so on for the entire length of the vector

So far, I created the vector and the empty vector

```
> y = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30)
> answer <- 0
```

And then, when I try to do the for loop, I get stuck here:

```
for(i in 1:length(y)){
if(i...){ ### ==1? ==0?
    answer = y[i]   ###and here I really don't know how to continue. 
}else if()
}
```

Believe me when I tell you I've read several replies to questions here, like in [How to make a vector using a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399868/how-to-make-a-vector-using-a-for-loop), plus pages and pages about for loop, but cannot really figure how to solve these (and other) problems.
I repeat, I'm very new, so I'm struggling trying to understand it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whoever is teaching you, tell them from the SO r-tag community to please stop teaching how to grow objects in a loop.

Comment: Also tell them to read [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) to learn the reasons why @Roland suggests "stop teaching how to grow objects in a loop."

Comment: For that matter, tell your classmate that it's insane to stick a conditional `if(i == 1) ` inside a loop. If the first value of your vector doesn't follow the pattern of the remainder, initialize outside the loop and do  `for(i = 2:n)`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Then at what point do we teach them that using `1:length(y)` to get a set of indexes to iterate over is a bad idea (namely when `y` might have length 0)? (For future readers, `seq_along(y)` is safer because it gives the intended results even when `y` is of length 0.)

Comment: @BrianDiggs well, philosophically, I prefer to check that `length(y)` is a useful value prior to doing anything with `y` :-)

Comment: I think teaching how to grow objects is not bad since it can help one transfer this knowledge across languages. Might be handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I will annotate the loop to answer what the loop is doing.

```
# Initialize the vector
x <- numeric()
for(i in 1:8){   
  # Initialize the first element of the vector, x[1].  Remember, R indexes start at 1, not 0.
  if(i==1){                
    x[i] <- 3              
  } else {   
    # Define each additional element in terms of the previous one (x[i - 1]
    # is the element of x before the current one.
    x[i] <- x[i-1]+2  ### And why i-1   
  }
}
```

A better solution that uses a loop and grows it (like the instructions state) is something like this:

```
x <- numeric()
for(i in 1:8){
  x[i] <- 2 * i + 1
}
```

This is still not a good way to do things because growing a vector inside a loop is *very* slow.  To fix this, you can preallocate the vector by telling `numeric` the length of the vector you want:

```
x <- numeric(8)
```

The best way to solve this would be:

```
2 * 1:8 + 1
```

using vectorized operations.

To help you solve your other problem, I suggest writing out each step of the loop as a table.  For example, for my solution, the table would be

```
i | x[i]
------------------
1 | 2 * 1 + 1 = 3
2 | 2 * 2 + 1 = 5
```

and so on.  This will give you an idea of what the for loop is doing at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This is intentionally not an answer because there are better ways to solve the alternating sign summation problem than a for-loop. I suppose there could be value in getting comfortable with for-loops but the vectorized approaches in R should be learned as well. R has "argument recycling" for many of its operations, including the "*" (multiplication) operation: Look at:

```
 (1:10)*c(1,-1)
```

Then take an arbitrary vector, say `vec` and try:

```
sum( vec*c(1,-1) )
```

The more correct answer after looking at that result would be:

```
vvec[1] + sum( vec[-1]*c(1,-1) )
```

Which has the educational advantage of illustrating R's negative indexing. Look up "argument recycling" in your documentation. The shorter objects are automagically duplicatied/triplicated/however-many-needed-cated to exactly match the length of the longest vector in the mathematical or logical expression.

Comment: I think for loops are easier when starting because you can tell R to do something the way you think. When using vectorization in R, you first have to understand how R thinks and then change your methods to accommodate R. And I don't think it is bad not to mention pre-allocation @Roland or optimization because when people are learning (well, for me at least), I wasn't thrown into a situation working with huge databases where it was pivotal to optimize code and worry about memory management.

Comment: @rawr I don't agree fully. Pre-allocation is easy and easy to explain. One could still show that growing objects is possible, but after teaching pre-allocation and clearly explaining why it should be avoided.

Comment: It can be explained in a sentence or two and is good practice for later, so yeah you're probably right.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies! It helped a lot!