# 2 Vectors under for loop

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df with ID column. I am trying to make all possible combination between another vector called dates

```
df

ID
Asda
Dsaa
Fasd
Das

dates <- seq(as.Date("2019-12-27"), as.Date(" "), by=1)
```

I have written a following for loop. But I get only below result

```
for (i in df$ID) {
  for (j in dates) {
    new_value <- c(i, j)
  }
}
```

Result below

```
new_value
        ID        Date 
      "Das"     "18258"
```

Expected result is : Can i get all combination of ID and dates?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explaining a for loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116142/explaining-a-for-loop-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` to get all combinations of your variables:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("Asda", "Dsaa", "Fasd", "Das"))
dates <- seq(as.Date("2019-12-27"), as.Date("2019-12-28"), by=1)

merge(df, dates, by = NULL)
```

Result:

```
    ID          y
1 Asda 2019-12-27
2 Dsaa 2019-12-27
3 Fasd 2019-12-27
4  Das 2019-12-27
5 Asda 2019-12-28
6 Dsaa 2019-12-28
7 Fasd 2019-12-28
8  Das 2019-12-28
```

**Edit:** For loop only

```
new_df <- data.frame()
for (i in df$ID) {
  for (j in dates) {
    new_df <- rbind(new_df, data.frame(ID = i, Date = j))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But Actually I require in for loop only. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

All possible combinations of ID and dates

```
expand.grid(df$ID,dates)
```

**Edit:** using for loops

```
k=1
temp=matrix(NA,length(df$ID)*length(dates),2)
for (i in df$ID) {
    for (j in dates){
        temp[k,]=c(i,j)
        k=k+1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But Actually I require in for loop only. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a `for` loop but for the sake of completeness (`expand.grid` and `merge`are R `base` nice answers) here is another solution using `tidyr::crossing()`. I am not sure why you would do so here since it is harder to optimise (see here a nice article from Miles Mcbain [for-loops](https://milesmcbain.xyz/for-loops/) ).

```r
dfr <- data.frame(id = paste0("id", 1:10), dates = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2019-12-27"), by = 1, length.out = 10 ) )
dfr
#>      id      dates
#> 1   id1 2019-12-27
#> 2   id2 2019-12-28
#> 3   id3 2019-12-29
#> 4   id4 2019-12-30
#> 5   id5 2019-12-31
#> 6   id6 2020-01-01
#> 7   id7 2020-01-02
#> 8   id8 2020-01-03
#> 9   id9 2020-01-04
#> 10 id10 2020-01-05

tidyr::crossing(dfr$id, dfr$dates)
#> # A tibble: 100 x 2
#>    `dfr$id` `dfr$dates`
#>    <fct>    <date>     
#>  1 id1      2019-12-27 
#>  2 id1      2019-12-28 
#>  3 id1      2019-12-29 
#>  4 id1      2019-12-30 
#>  5 id1      2019-12-31 
#>  6 id1      2020-01-01 
#>  7 id1      2020-01-02 
#>  8 id1      2020-01-03 
#>  9 id1      2020-01-04 
#> 10 id1      2020-01-05 
#> # ... with 90 more rows
```